# Can't install the PyQt5 - UI to py conversion issues because of multiple python versions

Tags: python, pyqgis, pyqt5

I have both Python 2.7 (which comes with ArcGIS) and 3.7 (which comes QGIS 3.4) - in normal command prompt its showing Python 3.7.0 and path from qgis 3.4. 
I confirmed version and path running following commands

```
python 

>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
```

[image: python version confirmation]

so I tried to install PyQt5 by the following command

```
pip install PyQt5
```

but the command prompt throws the

> DEPRECATION : Python 2.7 will reach ...

error.

[image: pip installation error]

So as command prompt suggested I tried to upgrade the pip version by using following commands

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

but again I got the different error like

> already up-to-date

[image: updated error]

I don't know what to do.  Is there any problem with Version (2.7 or 3.7 issues) else am I doing mistake on installing/setting up with environment variables.

Note: I'm in the process of developing a tool which uses PyProj, GDAL, so I used Qt Designer for front-end. trying to convert UI to py. I'm a beginner so messed-up with these things.

Comment: You'll need to open the osgeo4w shell and execute py3_env.bat to activate py3 in that shell. Did you? If you want to use Pyqt5 you have to run qt5_env.bat before running pyrcc5 or pyuic5.